# What is the entry point of an AS3 script?

Tags: actionscript-3

What is the entry point of an AS3 script?

Are there any good very simple tutorials on using Flash CS4 (Windows)?

Answer (score 3):

If you specify a document class, the entry point would be the constructor of that class.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

You override initializationComplete()

```
override protected function initializationComplete():void
```

Or you call a method in your script directly from somewhere in a Flash application...in which case there really is no entry point.

As for good tutorials, Adobe probably has the best:

[Adobe - Flash Developer Center](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/) (look on the right hand nav bar for the tutorials)